# Does NAT address need to be the default gateway?

Tags: router, vlan, firewall, nat, network

I will use a firewall for NAT. The firewall will be part of a VLAN and will translate a machine network IP address for domain access requests. Should I set the devices on the network to use the Firewall VLAN as the default gateway or the NAT(Firewall itself) as the default gateway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a single IP address on the VLAN provides the uplink for the firewall ("WAN side") while the machine network addresses (on the "LAN side") are to be translated to this VLAN IP - this isn't quite clear from your question:

The machine network devices need the IP address of the firewall on the LAN side as default gateway. A gateway needs to be inside a subnet, otherwise it can't be used. (You can't reach a gateway through another gateway.)

Since you're planning to source NAT the LAN side IP addresses you don't need to set up a back route into the machine network.

Answer (score 3):

The host gateway should be set to the layer-3 device (firewall, router, etc.) address on the same network as the host. The gateway is the host on the network that knows how to reach other networks. If the gateway is configured as an address on a different network, you would need a gateway to reach the gateway, so it will not work.

Comment: Ron if the 192 address is being NATed  to an address on the same subnet as the gateway, wont any unknown packets then be sent to packets on the LAN subnet? or do they need to be routed out from the inside to the outside requiring a 192 default gateway.?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If a host on a network is sending to another host on the same network, the packets will not pass through a router, so the packets will not run through the NAT process. In a router, you configure the router to use NAT, or not, between different interfaces. Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network.

Comment: so the inside 192 clients need the inside interfaces ip as de

Comment: @DavyGravy, the configured gateway for a host _must be on the same network as the host_." A host cannot use a gateway on a different network because it would need a gateway to the gateway. NAT happens inside a gateway, and it is transparent to the host. The configured gateway of a host is the gateway interface on the same network as the host. The gateway itself takes care of routing the packets to a different network, and performing NAT, if it is configured to do so between interfaces.